# different between select and delete in symfony2 doctrine time to execute

Tags: symfony, time, doctrine

I am deleting some rows from DB (few) 1 usally...

But when i check profiler there are three queries:

First two are just select user => time is about: Time: **1.31 ms**

And third query is delete:

```
DELETE 
FROM 
 likes
WHERE 
 user_id = ? AND status_id = ?
```

Both foreign keys and indexes.

And the time is: Time: **30.55 ms**

Isn't that too much somehow? Or its fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SELECT` statement is, in general, faster.

Remember that before `DELETE` a row (or a set of row), DBMS have to find ("so select") which row have to be involved and, then, delete those.
Maybe he have to delete also, in cascade fashion, other records in many tables and even reindex these tables so, yes, is quite normal

Comment: ok than. that i needed to know. Just was making me sure and comfortable to feel absolutly normal that the bigger time is not my programing mystake . Thx